# How to show that every symmetric nonsingular complex matrix can be written as $A=P^ T P$ form

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I know that if we have a positive definite matrix then we can show that A=$P^T P$

But here I had given to prove for a complex matrix which needs to be hermitian.

**It is not duplicate AS My question is for symmetric complex matrix Not Hermitian**

Please help me

I'm stuck here, any hint will be appreciated

Comment: Sir I have symmetric complex matrix I read it is for real hermitian

Comment: Look for Takagi's factorization: write $A=U^TDU$ and split $D=D^{1/2}D^{1/2}$.

Comment: See also [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Complex_symmetric_matrices)